# Avoid updating timestamps - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can i avoid updating timestamps for the following query:

```
$users = User::where('activated', 0)->update(array('activated' => 1));
```

I know, i can use the following approach:

```
$users = User::where('activated', 0)->get();

foreach($users as $user)
{
  $user->timestamps = false;
  $user->activated = 1;
  $user->save();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any other way for a collection. But for a model it is possible to have a one liner.

Comment: This will block the updating timestamps in whole website.

Comment: You might want to turn `timestamp = true`; after the save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to run triggers/events/validation/etc, you may use query builder:

```
DB::table('users')->where('activated', 0)->update(array('activated' => 1));
```

Alternatively, you may modify your model (probably some `Base` model) and add method like this:

```
public function updateWithoutTimestamps(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->timestamps = false;
    $result = $this->update($attributes);
    $this->timestamps = true;
    return $result;
}
```

This should do the trick.

```
$users = User::where('activated', 0)->updateWithoutTimestamps(array('activated' => 1));
```

However, I prefer first way just because updating a flag seems like a one-time action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this should be an array `->update(array('activated'=> 1));`

Comment: I will accept your answer if no one has any other solution with Eloquent.

Comment: [According the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/254497b8672e90ca6ee562a3d1fe9eab540daabe/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L294) other solutions are impossible with current Eloquent implementation